# Print preview performance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, printing

My question is pretty straightforward. I need to display a print preview dialog in a multi-user ERP environment. It speaks for itself that printing should be as fast as possible.
However, if I use the code below, it takes about 10! seconds before the preview is displayed and is fully generated. This is without database access or any other CPU intensive operations.

Is there any way or method to improve this performance? I'm also able to use WPF, should that be necessary.

I've noticed that if you generate the preview, close it, and then quickly generate it again, it responds much faster, about a second or two. If you then wait another 5 seconds or so, generate it again, it takes about 10 seconds again. 
I'm guessing some type of caching is going on, but don't have a clue what's actually happening.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PrintPerformanceTests
{
    public class PrintPreviewTest
    {
        private string printerName;
        private PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1;
        private PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
        private Random random = new Random();

        public string PrinterName
        {
            get { return printerName; }
            set { printerName = value; }
        }

        public PrintPreviewDialog PrintPreviewDialog
        {
            get { return printPreviewDialog1; }
            set { printPreviewDialog1 = value; }
        }

        public PrintPreviewTest(string printerName, PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog)
        {
            this.PrinterName = printerName;
            this.PrintPreviewDialog = printPreviewDialog;
            printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
        }

        public void GenerateRandomPrintPreview()
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            try
            {
                PrintPreviewDialog.Document = printDocument1;
                PrintPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }

        void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
            using(Font f = new Font("Arial", 10f))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    string txt = "Random string " + i.ToString();
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(txt, f, Brushes.Black, new PointF(random.Next(10, 200), random.Next(10,280)));
                }
            }

            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
        PrintPreviewTest pt = new PrintPreviewTest(tbPrinter.Text, printPreviewDialog);
        pt.GenerateRandomPrintPreview();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this startup delay is related to initialization of printer parameters. When you set printer name (especially network printer name) and create print preview dialog, it first connects to the specified printer and checks it's settings (paper size etc.). It takes a lot of time. The only way (IMHO) to overcome this issue is to create your own print preview dialog that initializes printer settings in separate thread.

Comment: Print preview without information about paper supported by selected printer, maximum printable area dimensions, default print settings, etc, etc is not worth much, IMHO. I wrote my own print previewer and after third or fourth iteration I concluded these settings are important, so I'm actually doing the same thing, but only once per application instance per printer. Then I add "refresh" button should anyone change default print settings while instance was active. And also querying one printer takes near no-time, unless it's both networked and unavailable (my experience).